# Why is my Create-React-App not displaying when I serve an index.html file with Express to Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I found my issue but don't know how to solve it. In my deployed Heroku app, I am getting errors in the console saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" for chunk.js. It seems that Chunk.js is coming in as an HTML file instead of a JS file. This is happening because, in my routes.js file, it is serving the index.html file in the catch-all endpoint ('/*'). I don't believe that the web browser is able to find my chunk.js and manifest.json files. When I remove my catch-all endpoint and leave the endpoint ('/'), I get a 404 module not found an error for all of the files in my build folder. It may help to know my React app is using routing for different pages.

Also, my app works when I run it locally with two separate servers (client server and backend server). But I can't get it to work by serving static files from the React build folder. I need to serve static files for production.

**Here is my routes.js file:**

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const root = require('path').join(__dirname,"../client","build")
app.use(express.static(root))

module.exports = function(app, db) {

    app.get('/categories', (req, res) => {
        const categories = {
            "categories": ["Gas", "Dining", "Groceries", "Online Shopping", "Travel", "Other"],
            "cardtype": ["Visa", "Amex", "Mastercard", "Discover"],
            "interest": [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6]
        }
        res.send(categories);
    });
}

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile("index.html", {root})
    });

    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile("index.html", {root})
    });
}
```

**My package.json File in Client**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "https://myappurl.herokuapp.com/",
  "proxy":"http://localhost:5000/",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "6.13.4",
    "node": "12.15.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "stop": "taskkill -F -IM node.exe"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.5"
  }
}
```

**The Errors I am getting in console**
[image]

**File Directory**
[image]

Comment: What is code you have written in your `server.js` and `routes.js`

Comment: Also, check your console to get the exact error. There are 12 error messages in your console.

Comment: Hi @SonuBamniya I added my server.js file, index.js, and routes.js. Also, I attached a picture of the errors in my console. Seems that there's some issues with manifest.json. I believe it's that I don't have the images that manifest.json is telling me to load (favicon.ico, logo192,logo512). However, I don't know if that would cause my components not to load

Comment: I doubt that a missing manifest is the reason your page wont load. But what i can tell from the error messages is that your server is only serving the index.html file. However a react app needs many more files in order to function, you need to configure your server.js file in a way that these files are sent as well.

Comment: @Dwagh thank you for your input. I am not sure how I would configure my server.js file. I suspected that was the cause of the error, but I could not find a solution online. The examples I’ve seen simply serve the index.html file like I have in routes.js.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3

Comment: @Dwagh Thanks for sending this, I actually used this article to help before. I seem to have everything setup just like the article, I don't see where the article does anything unique to make sure the react app is being served properly. All they do is add "proxy" parameter to package.json file and serve the static html file from index.js, just like I do.

Comment: @Dwagh Ok so it seems that my build file isnt compressing correctly. When i open index.html locally from the build directory in react, the components don't load because the console throws errors that it cannot find my chunk files even though they exist

Comment: Try serving the build folder instead of the public folder. Usually public folder contains source files and not compiled files? So just execute whatever command you use to build your react app and then serve that

Comment: @Dwagh Ok thank you, I served the build folder. However, there is one more underlying issue, I am getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'". for my chunk.js file. I made lots of edits to my question so you can see clearly. I have spent hours trying to fix this but don't know how. I believe my chunk.js file is being sent as an incorrect type "HTML" instead of a js file.

Comment: Ok that chunk is obviously a html file not a js file. What is the content of your build folder?

Comment: @Dwagh I posted the file directory of my build folder, and also an example of what chunk.js file looks like in my local build folder. its a js file as it should be. but it somehow changes when it gets pushed to heroku.

Comment: I'd say in your routes.js file the line with `app.get('*', ...)` is the problem. No matter what resource is requested from your server you always send the index.html file. Even if chunk.js is request you respond with index.html

Comment: @Dwagh when i remove app.get('*', ...), i get an 404 module not found error that the files in my build file are not found. I do not know how to configure this correctly. I put an updated image of my file directory.